# XML Datatype hierarchy is based on?

Tags: xml, types

I'm wondering how the datatype hierarchy was done. 
For example, why the datatypes datetime and time don't have a hierarchical relation like father and son?. Why they are in the same level as two completely different datatypes if they share the time?.

Maybe there are rules about that and I didn't find it.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XSD 1.0 specification claims that the data types were "judiciously chosen". I have always assumed this was a euphemism for saying "we spent an awfully long time talking about it and this was the best agreement we could get".

It's worth remembering that the XML Schema WG in those early days was very large (I seem to remember hearing there was one meeting with 40 people present) and there were a wide variety of views on every subject. Getting a coherent set of datatypes in that kind of group is not going to be easy.